# Reading alt code JTextArea

Tags: java, ascii

I have a barcode that reads :
"SerialNumber<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>ProductNumber"
where <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> = <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I read the number in to a `JTextArea`, if i write the number manually with the tab key on my keyboard i get a valid input i can then `text.trim().split("\t");` 
to get a valid input to get respective serial number and product number. But when reading the barcode who sends <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> it does not read anything.

How do i get the `JTextArea` to accept <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> as <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or as alternative split on the location).

Comment: You could use a DocumetFilter

Answer (score 0):

JTextArea is not getting Tab at all. Tab is interrupted by whole GUI interface to switch to next editable field. Of course you can bend this rule, intercept Tab on parent container and force it to send it to the child JTextArea and then you can even write your won method for KeyPressed event and insert Tab character into the text but it's good approach because it changes user experience. User expects Tab to go to next field but for this particular text area you say that it should be delimiter for your text? Another reason - Tab is similar for Space - so in user experience it's not clear was input right or not.

To avoid all these troubles why not take simple approach:

```
SerialNumber=ProductNumber
```

It is clear, visible, predictable, understandable and most off all - doesn't required your question ;)

Comment: The Text area is getting tab. If i press the tab key there is a tab distance in the field. I have an idea you might confuse TextField with TextArea, Also in user experience, they just scan the barcode. And the simple approach is not so simple, since the Serial number is not The product number. The serial number is unique, for every item. it is a 1 to 1 relationship where there can be alot of the same product. = same product.